# Z-index problems in IE Quirks mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I'm working on this site: http://stdionis.org.uk/

When the site is viewed in IE 9 or below, the drop down menus on the home page appear underneath the slideshow (It's a google slideshow), however when you go to another page, the drop-downs appear on top of images.

I've set the z-index of the drop-down div to 9999, and I've tried setting the z-index of the slideshow to zero, but I can't seem to make it work.

The CMS we are using doesn't directly allow access to the HTML code of the page (don't ask...) so I can only use CSS or javascript to make changes. Hence why i can't change the doctype to make it display in standards mode.

Not looking for a clean solution necessarily, any crazy javascript hacks would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
.t_horizontal * { z-index: 1000 !important; }
```

or

```
.t_horizontal table { z-index: 1000 !important; }
```

if even not working then - try using jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.t_horizontal *').css('z-index','1000 !important');
});
```

*NOTE: menu is using table which is not proper way to build menu.*

Comment: thanks, that doesn't seem to have worked though. it seems as though whenever a new image fades in, it is on top by default. i know it's awful code, i wish i could edit it but unfortunately I have no access to the code and the menu is generated automatically by the CMS.

Comment: try add this  - #slideshow { z-index:100 } .t_horizontal, .t_horizontal *, .t_horizontal div, .t_horizontal:hover { z-index:1000 }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
#ctlHeaderModules {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#frm1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Both of these two elements are on the same level and when I inspect them in Chrome I dont see any of these properties being applied, its worth a shot.

There is also this plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TopZIndex